# How to change the virtualenv for emacs virtualenv.el

Tags: emacs, elisp, virtualenv

I tried to use virtualenv virtualenv.el file posted [here](https://github.com/aculich/virtualenv.el).

But I set the wrong directory.  (Moreover, it seems that it requires I put my virtualenvs in the .virtualenv directory, not in the disparate directories where I've written them on my machine.)

How can I change this back?  Now when I run `M-x virtualenv-workon` I don't have the same intro prompt I had the first time.

**Update**

Following the note left in the comments and the documentation, I added the following file to my project folder:

```
/home/fred/projectname/.dir-locals.el
```

this contains the following:

```
((nil . ((virtualenv-workon . "venv")
         (virtualenv-default-directory . "/home/fred/projectname/venv"))))
```

However, still when I open emacs in my project directory and type `M-x virtualenv-workon` it only finds local (default) not venv.  What am I missing?

Comment: Have you read the Commentary section in virtualenv.el?  It explains how to setup the `.dir-locals.el` in your "random directories".

Comment: OK, I changed "random directories" above to "disparate directories." Thanks.  I don't really understand what dir-locals is. When reading the commentary section it said something like "You should read the dir-locals docs to understand the format," which also seemed unclear to me.  Were you able to understand what that meant for local project venv directories?

Comment: a `/foo/bar/.dir-locals.el` file lets you configure Emacs behavior for all the files in `/foo/bar/`.  So you place such a file in the root of each project.

Comment: Your post refers to [my old virtualenv package](https://github.com/aculich/virtualenv.el) that I no longer maintain; there are at least 3 newer, actively maintained packages: [virtualenvwrapper](https://github.com/porterjamesj/virtualenvwrapper.el), [pyvenv](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/pyvenv), [python-environment](https://github.com/tkf/emacs-python-environment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had the same problem. I know the post is older and virtualenv.el is depricated, but in case anybody else also stumbles across this:

When you run `M-x virtualenv-workon` for the first time, it creates an entry in your .emacs file. The file should be found in your home directory. The entry is under custom-set-variables and is called virtualenv-root. You can open the file and adjust the path manually to whatever location you would like.